# Hyperledger Fabric network with single orderer using etcdraft Consensus orderer always becomes follower

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-orderer

I am trying to set up a network with a single orderer using etcdraft as consensus mechanism because I later want to add extra orderers. But for some reason my orderer always becomes a follower, while there are no other orderers to follow. How does the orderer determine to become a follower or a consenter? What does he check to check if he is part of the consenters or not? Is there an easy way to debug this?

I checked the certificates from the `configtx.yaml` Consenters and it's the same as the one from the orderer itself ...

My current configuration can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/daanporon/5e4f2fc5270dfb99e4da7b3d1d343c75

Thanks in advance,

Greets,

Daan

Answer (score 0):

In my case i found out that it was an issue with the certificate. The one that was used for creating the channel had a newline at the end and the one from the orderer didn't had it. I presume this fix will fix this in the future:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/issues/3998